# open source spider to get links from web page , what is the fastest way?

Tags: c++, web-crawler

I need to crawl web pages and extract only the links from the pages. Links can be 
relative, like :

```
...\blah\foo.html
```

What is the fastest way to do this ?

1. Get web page
2. Extract links from any form

**update :**

Maybe what I need is `htmlparser`?

Comment: You might want to check `wget` source code, which has the ability to extract URLs from HTML and CSS files (-i option).

Comment: Is the web-pages on a server or on a local filesystem? I ask because you use _backslash_ as directory separator which is only use locally on Windows systems.

Comment: server i just use example but you get the point
i like to avoid to dig into wget source code . im short in time

Comment: How simple are the pages? Do you need to process JavaScript?

Comment: To get the files check e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), or [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html).

Comment: For parsing see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/800104/440558).

Comment: this is great , i will use libxml2 , but i can't find any good examples or tutorials on the HTMLparser , its only on xml